# Is there a way to get the name of a file using the Google Drive API?

Tags: android, mime-types, google-drive-android-api

Let's say I use the Google Drive API to select a file that I want to open. I have this code to do so:

```
// Getting the drive ID for the file
        DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data
                .getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

        // Getting the selected file
        DriveFile googleDriveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(googleApiClient,
                driveId);

        googleDriveFile.open(googleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY,
                null).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
```

Is there any way for me to get the file name of this file? (Not the drive ID, but its actual name?)

I'm trying to validate the chosen file (by checking its type, which is in the name), and I can't think of a way to do this other than get the name. The type is .cblite, a Couchbase Lite database file. Normally I'd just filter the Drive picker by MIME type, but .cblite (to my knowledge) isn't one of those options. Instead I'm trying to validate by file name.

Is there a way to do this? (Or is there a way to filter MIME types by miscellaneous/unidentified types?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, once you have DriveId, you can get metadata. And one of the metadata fields is getTitle() which will get you the file / folder name. Look at this code snippet:

```
DriveFile googleDriveFile  = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(googleApiClient, driveId);
MetadataResult mdRslt = googleDriveFile .getMetadata(googleApiClient).await();
if (mdRslt != null && mdRslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
  mdRslt.getMetadata().getTitle();
}
```

The 'await' flavor here is used for convenience, it must be run off-ui thread. Or just turn it into a callback style.

Good Luck

Comment: Christina, most of your questions can be answered by stepping through  Github GDAADemo I pointed out in your previous question SO 28439129. For instance, the MIME type can be solved by just asking for mime type  here: https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/GooDrive.java#L113. You have to figure out what CBLITE mime type string is, though.

Comment: .. it just occurred to me, if you search for your CBLITE files (you have to get everything and filter it locally, since there is no 'wildcard' support) and just read the 'getMimeType()' field, you'll figure what the string is. Consider also this playground https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list , it is designed for RESTful API, but since GDAA is build on top of it, you can run a lot of tests interactively there.

Comment: TITLE! Darn, sorry, I was looking up "get file name," "not get file title," and found no results.

Also, there is no MIME type for .cblite. I've looked into that already.

Comment: Got no clue what CBLITE is. But I would take one '*.cblite' file  (coming from some CBLITE application), upload it to the Drive and use the playground I mentioned above to check what the metadata look like. Or send me a dummy one to seanpjanson@gmail.com and I'll look at it.

Comment: @Christina if you think the answer is accurate, please accept it as correct, so others can benefit.